# How to align data in to view port. Stuck for a while now

Tags: extjs, extjs3

Team,

How to align data in to view port. I have two panels and unable to achieve the desired effect. I am using extjs 3.4

I am facing the following problems:

1. Border are over lapping and it is coming very thick. Not able to leave space from top and left.
2. Not able to set height and it is expanding up to whole page.
3. Grid and panel width should be reduced I have only three columns

code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-3.4.0/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<style type="text/css">
.add24 {
    background-image: url(images/fiber_Cable.jpg) !important;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-3.4.0/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-3.4.0/ext-all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.onReady(function() {
        var baseParamsv = {
        "pager":""
        };

        Ext.QuickTips.init();

        var searchFormPanel = new Ext.FormPanel({
            id: 'searchForm'
            ,region:'north'
            ,title:'Heading'
            ,layout:'table'
            ,bodyStyle:'padding:10px;'
            ,height:100
            ,width:200
            ,padding: '5 5 5 5' 
            ,layoutConfig: {columns: 2}
            ,defaults: {ctCls:'padding3'}
        });
        searchFormPanel.add({xtype: 'label', text:'Search User:'});
        searchFormPanel.add({xtype: 'label', text: ''});
        searchFormPanel.add({xtype: 'textfield', id: 'search1', name: 'search1', value: '',enableKeyEvents: true});
        searchFormPanel.add({xtype: 'button', id: 'go', cls: 'spacing3', text: 'Go!', handler:function() {} });

        var gridColumnModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
        { header: "checked",sortable:true, menuDisabled:true, dataIndex:'checked',width:20,renderer:checkBoxRenderer},
        { header: "username",sortable:true, menuDisabled:true, dataIndex:'username',width:40,renderer:UserNameRenderer},
        { header: "emailid",sortable:true, menuDisabled:true, dataIndex:'emailid',width:30, renderer:emailidRenderer}
    ]);     
    var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({    
            baseParams:baseParamsv,
            fields: [
                {name:'checked'},
                {name:'username'},
                {name:'emailid'}
            ],
            root:'data',
            totalProperty: 'total',
            url:'data.json',
            id:'offlineDataStoreId' 
    });






    var dataGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
            colModel:gridColumnModel
            ,region:'center'
            ,store:store
            ,stripeRows:true
            ,viewConfig: { autoFill:true, emptyText : 'No data found to display', forceFit: true, scrollOffset: 2 }
            ,layout:'fit'
            ,listeners: {
                    render: function(){
                        var initParams =  Ext.apply({},baseParamsv);
                        Ext.apply(initParams, {
                             start:0,
                             limit:10
                        });
                        this.store.load({params:initParams});
                    }
                }
        });



    function checkBoxRenderer(val, meta, record, rowIndex, colIndex, offlineStore) {
        return '<input type=checkbox name="check_box" value="'+record.get('emailid')+'">';
    }

    function UserNameRenderer(val, meta, record, rowIndex, colIndex, offlineStore) {
        return val;
    }

    function emailidRenderer(val, meta, record, rowIndex, colIndex, offlineStore) {

        return val;
    }


        var innerPanel = {
        xtype: 'panel',
        id: 'inner-panel',
        layout: 'border',
        region: 'center',
        title:'Heading',
        width:200,
        bodyStyle:'padding:10px;',
        padding: '5 5 5 5' ,
        items :[dataGrid]
        };


         var viewPort = new Ext.Viewport({
            layout: 'border',
            title: 'Ext Layout Browser',
            items:[searchFormPanel,innerPanel],
            bodyStyle:'padding:10px;margin-top:10px',
            renderTo:Ext.getBody()
        });
        viewPort.doLayout();


    });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use whole the page, just use a panel instead of a Viewoprt:

```
var viewPort = new Ext.Panel({
    layout: 'border',
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    title: 'Ext Layout Browser',
    items:[searchFormPanel,innerPanel],
    bodyStyle:'padding:10px;margin-top:10px',
    renderTo:Ext.getBody()
});
```

Here you can see the result: http://jsfiddle.net/3CabN/6/

Comment: Thank you very much Darin. How to leave spaces from bottom and top and broders are very thick I am struggling to get over that.